# Entity Framework: Many-to-one Association with self referencing

Tags: entity-framework

I have some problem creating the association with Entity Framework Code First.

In this problem, i have a class - lets call it ClassA which looks like

```
public class ClassA
{
     [Key]
     public int ClassAId { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("FromClassAId")]
     public virtual List<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}
```

There i have a association Table (because i have alot of associations and don't want to create douzends of associations table). In this association Table i have a reference back to ClassA. Then Association-Class looks like

```
public class Association
{
     [Key]
     public int AssociationId { get; set; }

     public int FromClassAId { get; set; }

     public int ClassAId { get; set; }

     public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
}
```

So, from ClassA there is a reference to Association over ClassA:ClassAId -> Association:FromClassAId and then a reference from Association:ClassA(ClassAId) -> ClassA:ClassAId

So, following data in the database

**ClassA**

```
ClassAId     Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            Test Data 1
2            Test Data 2
3            Test Data 3
```

**Association**

```
AssociationId     FromClassAId    ClassAId
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 1               2
1                 1               3
```

Should return following object (with .Include("Associations").Include("Associations.ClassA") (just json format for better seeing :) )

```
{
  ClassAId: 1,
  Name: 'Test Data 1',
  Associations: 
  [
    {
      FromClassAId: 1,
      ClassAId: 2,
      ClassA: 
      {
        ClassAId: 2,
        Name: 'Test Data 2'
      }
    },
    {
      FromClassAId: 1,
      ClassAId: 3,
      ClassA: 
      {
        ClassAId: 3,
        Name: 'Test Data 3'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With the ForeignKey set like above, i get the association-reference, but not the "self"-referencing back to the ClassA Object from Association. I tried several configurations, but i won't get the ClassA Reference successfully back. Maybe i make a brain-bug :)

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution, after debuging and using the SQL Profiler, maybe someone has the same problem.

```
public class ClassA
{
     [Key]
     public int ClassAId { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("ClassAId")]
     public virtual List<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}

public class Association
{
     [Key]
     public int AssociationId { get; set; }

     public int ClassAId { get; set; }

     public int ToClassAId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("ToClassAId")]
     public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe EF has some problems when using two FK together, where only the back reference in the child class is named like the primary key in the mother class.

Comment: Is there a type-o in the Association table you put? It looks like duplicated primary key.

Comment: Hi, i can't see a type-o. The Primary Key for this table is AssociationId. There are two references from the / to the ClassA table. FromClassAId is the reference used by ClassA to do the association between ClassA and Association (one-to-many) and ClassAId should be used for the one-to-one reference from Assocation to ClassA (over the ClassA Object inside Association).

Comment: what i see in the Association table sample entries there are two rows with AssociationId of 1. In your data model you specify the primary key as AssociationId, so i was wondering if this is fake data, otherwise you would have a duplicated primary key?

Comment: Ah, i see - yes, that's a type-o in the example datas. I just looked over the class definition. You are right, the second line should have a AssociationId of 2

Answer (score 0):

In code-first, you as a developer shouldn't worry about how the database will reflect your data model, just create C# classes that make sense for your data/domain model (in most cases anyways). This is the philosophical difference behind object-relational-mappers like EF-Code first. You play the role of software developer, and let EF-Code First be the DBA (for the basics at least).

Instead of an "Association" type and worrying about the table, just have a list of the same object.

```
public class ClassA
{
     [Key]
     public int ClassAId { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual List<ClassA> Associations { get; set; }
}
```

…Then your eager loading using .Include("Associations") will work. The "FromClassAId" becomes implied by the fact that you find an instance of ClassA in some other instance's Association property.

Leave it to Entity Framework to create a sql schema that works for adds, deletes, etc… If the schema that EF creates is not to your liking, then you can start adding attributes, fluent api modifications, etc.

Comment: Yes, that works, but i will have later in this association table classb, classc etc. where the association can have references back to other classa (or classb) types. So, instead of changing alot of entities, i just have to change the global association table, when i have a new table/entity.

Comment: @jjf without knowing more about the problem you are trying to model in C#, i would just recommend thinking about the problem and how it makes sense in C# not in SQL. Thinking about SQL with EF-CodeFirst is, to me, a code smell unless your trying to work around a limitation of EF's. If you are thinking about sql implementation in C# your not using EF for its intended purpose or to its maximum power.

Comment: Yes, EF has Pro and Cons. I allways take a look at the database definition generated by EF Migrations and change it, when needed. I don't think, that using EF Code-First with keeping an eye on the database structure generated is an antagonism. Code design is allways standing between performance, type safety, expansibility and (Unit) testing.